# Why sigma bond has C2 symmetry not C∞?

Tags: bond, orbitals, symmetry

I have seen some books indicated sigma bond has C2 symmetry. I understand pi and delta bond change their signs about C2 and C4 rotation about bond axis, but I don't  understand why sigma bond has C2 symmetry not C∞ about its bond axis.
The example of the sigma bond came from two 1s orbitals.

Comment: I have seen books about two-headed people living beyond the ocean. Somehow, this does not bother me one bit. A sigma bond is $C_\infty$-symmetric all right.

Comment: Possibly they meant C2 around an axis *perpendicular* to the bond, especially since 1s orbital bonding is H2, which is symmetric.

Comment: Technically speaking a $\sigma$ bond fits in the $C_{2}$ point group since $C_{2}\subset C_{\infty}$.

Comment: @Andrew the book indicates the rotation axis with the bond axis.